# Excel show percentage of subtotal

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I need to show values  as a percentage but not as grant total, but i want to show a percentage of grant subtotal as shown in the image
[image]

Comment: Please try to avoid external links. You can include images in your question directly in it if needed

Comment: Is "Grant Total" anything like "Grand Total" :)? On a serious note, you may need to use a calculated field for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you need to change the layout of your PivotTable to get the answer.

At the moment, your layout looks like this:

[image]

To get the result you need, you need to change your layout to this:

[image]

(Note that I've turned off SubTotals from the previous image, because they make things look messy).

...then right click on one of the Values cells and select this:

[image]

...which gives you this:

[image]

...which is exactly the info you want, albeit in a slightly different layout.

Comment: @HaithamdarDar if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.